# Can I do this with customErrors?

Tags: c#, .net, redirect, url-rewriting, webforms

I've edited the webconfig in my Web Application (WebForms, .NET 4) adding this :

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="CustomError.aspx" redirectMode="ResponseRewrite">
    <error statusCode="404" redirect="CustomError.aspx" />
</customErrors>
```

now, If I request this page http://localhost/TestRedirect/asdasdasd (which it doesnt exist) I'd like to get the CustomError.aspx page (where I'll evalutate the page and redirect to the right source).

But in fact I get the HTTP 404.0 - Not Found. Unfortunatly I can't use httpErrors (due to my hosting permission), but maybe I can do it with customErrors? Or any other suggesions would be appreciated...

Comment: Make sure you have CustomError.aspx page and given proper path for the file CustomError.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your request is not coming to ASP.Net engine. Your customErrors tag will work fine if you use the url like

```
http://localhost/TestRedirect/asdasdasd.aspx
```

What version of IIS your webhosting provider has?

Comment: 7.5! Well, with asdasdasd.aspx it works! But I don't want asdasdasd.aspx, just asdasdasd :)

Comment: Make sure you are using Integrated Pipeline instead of classic.

Comment: bad luck  :( which hosting are you using? You may also consider a url rewriter if you intentionally want extentionless url may be to make some short url website.

Comment: I have an Aruba hosting. url rewriter? Is what I have to do :)

Comment: Refer this. It might help  http://urlrewriter.net/index.php/support/reference/error-handler/custom-error-handler